# Imagick: How to append a grid of images with appendImages

Tags: php, imagick, pecl

I am not using exec command in php so I don't have access to run something like the following from the manual at: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/ where it states, "You can take this further to make a whole array of images, and build them either by rows, or by columns."

```
convert \( font_1.gif font_2.gif font_3.gif +append \) \
          \( font_4.gif font_5.gif font_6.gif +append \) \
          \( font_7.gif font_8.gif font_9.gif +append \) \
          \( -size 32x32 xc:none  font_0.gif +append \) \
          -background none -append   append_array.gif
```

Using the http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.appendimages.php appendImages function in imagick how can I simulate the seemingly more robust append CLI command to append images by rows and columns? Or is it not possible by simply using the appendImages function in imagick?

I would love to be able to create an array in php like the following, loop through it, and on each new row, somehow tell appendImages using imagick, when it should start a new row before combining images.

```
$rack = [
            'row1' => [
                'image1.jpg',
                'image2.jpg'
            ],
            'row2' => [
                'image3.jpg',
                'image4.jpg'
            ]
        ];
```

My question is, how do you use [appendImages](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.appendimages.php) in imagick or other functions in imagick to achieve a similar result as the CLI convert -append command?

I know I could use other functions like compositeImage and use x,y to control positioning, but simply appending in rows would be much, much simpler for my use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow a two-phases procedure using just `appendImages()` (similar to what that command seems to do):

1. Iterate over the rows appending the content of each row horizontally from left to right with `appendImages()` specifying `stack=false`
2. Append all resulting Imagick row objects vertically from top to bottom with `appendImages()` specifying `stack=true`

Like this:

```
$rack = [
        'row1' => [
            'image1.jpg',
            'image2.jpg'
        ],
        'row2' => [
            'image3.jpg',
            'image4.jpg'
        ]
    ];

$fullimage = new Imagick();

foreach ($rack as $k => $v) {
    $rowimg = new Imagick();
    foreach ($v as $imagelocation) {
       $rowimg->readImage($imagelocation);
    }
    $rowimg->resetIterator();
    $combinedrow = $rowimg->appendImages(false);
    $fullimage->addImage($combinedrow);
}

$fullimage->resetIterator();
$finalimage = $fullimage->appendImages(true); // <-- Done.
```

Comment: Awesome! I never though that resetIterator was needed to allow it to work. Do you know if there's any other functions that require resetIterator to be called before the function, to allow the function to work correctly?

Comment: Sadly that function is not even properly documented, it should be needed only when working with PixelIterators but i guess that appendImages is one of the functions that use them internally (why not calling reset internally too then??). I don't remember other functions needing something like this, but i highly doubt that appendImages is the only one...

Comment: Well, if you find any others please can you report them at https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/ and they might get fixed one day.

Comment: One More Thing to Note, if for some reason, appendImages returns a null when calling it without the stack boolean (false/true) then add it (that was the case that fixed the null issue in my case, which is: real images loaded from the local machine)

Comment: @Cu7l4ss You just saved my night!  This is not documented anywhere that I could find.  Ridiculous library.